# PowerBI Filter All on 2 Columns DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following data;

- List of vendors some work within the same industry
- Vendor rating score
- Vendor industry
- Median measure for vendor score

I want to show a selected vendor that has been drilled into from a matrix is performing against other vendors who are in the same industry and postcode based on the vendor score for example comparing Vendor 1 and Vendor 2 from the below data sample

Data looksd like the following

[image]

I was playing around with the following dax which I know does not work

Vendor Peer Comparison = CALCULATE(
[Median Vendor Score],
FILTER(
ALL( 'VendorTable'[vendor_industry], 'VendorTable'[vendor_postcode])))

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

,Please try this: You can form a two slicers vendor_industry and vendor_postcode and pick the one you want to compare.

DAX Code:

```
Vendor_Peer_Comparison =
VAR VendorIndustry =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'VendorTable'[vendor_industry] )
VAR VendorPostcode =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'VendorTable'[vendor_postcode] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [Median Vendor Score],
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'VendorTable'[vendor_industry], 'VendorTable'[vendor_postcode] ),
            'VendorTable'[vendor_industry] = VendorIndustry
                && 'VendorTable'[vendor_postcode] = VendorPostcode
        )
    )
```

Comment: thank you for response. I tried using the abovr but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a matrix with the table as on your picture, even filtered by vendors name then the measure for the matrix is:

```
CALCULATE(
    [Median Vendor Score]
    ,ALLEXCEPT(
            'VendorTable'
            ,'VendorTable'[vendor_industry]
            ,'VendorTable'[vendor_postcode]) 
)
```

If your visual is a card and a single vendor is somehow selected then:

```
    CALCULATE(
    [Median Vendor Score]
    ,ALL(
         'VendorTable'[Vendor]
         ,'VendorTable'[Vendor Score]
     ) 
)
```